# Are Maps from manifold with global coordinates onto non-empty compact manifold automatically smooth?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $M$ be a manifold with a global chart, and let $N$ be a non-empty compact manifold.

Let $f\colon M\to N$ be a function such that $f(M)=N$.

To study the smoothness of $f$, I have to choose a point $x\in M$, a chart $U$ of $M$ around $x$ and a chart $V$ around $f(x)$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$. Next, I have to study the local representative of $f$ with respect to the selected charts.

In my case, the only possibility of a chart around any point of $M$ is the global one. Moreover, there exists no chart $(V,\psi)$ of $N$ such that $f(M)\subseteq V$ since $N$ can't be covered by a single chart.

> Why is this argument wrong?

Maybe the point is that equivalent classes of atlases give the differentiable structure of $M$. In particular, if $((V_i,\psi_i))_{i=1}^n$ is an atlas of $N$ and $(M,\varphi)$ is the global atlas of $M$, then $((f^{-1}(V_i),\varphi\restriction f^{-1}(V_i))_{i=1}^n$ is an equivalent atlas of $M$ such that $f(f^{-1}(V_i))=V_i$.

Comment: what's the relevance of compact here? also how can $N$ be non-empty if ultimately it's the image of a manifold with a global chart (a fortiori not empty right?) under some map?

Comment: There is no relevance at all. I needed only an example of a manifold whose atlases aren't singleton.

Comment: Parco Macelli, compact means non-singleton atlas?

Comment: If $(N,\psi)$ is a global chart of a compact manifold $N$, $\psi(N)$ is a compact and open set of $\mathbb R^{\dim N}$. Since $\mathbb R^{\dim N}$ is connected, $\psi(N)=\emptyset$ or $\psi(N)=\mathbb R$. The first case holds iff $N=\emptyset$ while the second one leads to a contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: What is a global chart again? Charts afair are usually local like at a point there exists a chart s.t. open subset of manifold is homeo / diffeo to an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. If there's a chart where the open subset is the manifold itself then...that makes the manifold homeo / diffeo to an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ ? Wait....aaaahhhh you're supposing on the contrary that the atlas is a singleton and so its lone chart is global? well i guess you're missing a step maybe that $\psi(N)$ is closed because compact subspace of Hausdorff is closed but ah yeah yeah ok thanks cool!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've pretty much answered your own question in the last paragraph: simply restrict $f$ to the chart $(f^{-1}(V_i), \phi \mid f^{-1}(V_i))$.

This is part of the reason underlying the concept of a "maximal" atlas. The global chart is not a maximal atlas all by itself.
But when formulating the maximal atlas that contains the global chart, you are forced to include all other charts formed from open subsets of that global chart, in particular the chart $(f^{-1}(V_i), \phi \mid f^{-1}(V_i))$.